# Find bounding points 2D with an "H" shape

Tags: java, geometry

I've got a set of points that represent a form like this:

[image]

As drawn on the picture, I would like to be able to detect the points that are bounding the "H" shape. Is there an algorithm to solve this problem?

I know there is a Graham scan that I could use, but the Graham scan will only take the points outside the cloud of points.

Comment: i don't understand how you could come out with that H shape. if you search for the bounding shape, it's a box made by the most outer 4 points; if you search the minimum area, you still don't get an H (using more points to form the edge)

Comment: It's exactly the point, I'm finding for an algorithm that could solve this problem

Comment: You can try alpha shapes. It's a delaunay triangulation without edges exceding alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Alpha shape algorithm](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Alpha_shapes_2/index.html) to build non-convex hulls. If your point cloud is properly formed (vertical sticks of H are well divided and so on...), you may try to build alpha shape, then correct it to rectilinear figure.

[image]